# Xbox and Playstation copyright protection vs PC

Tags: hardware, license-enforcement

AFAIK, both Xbox one and PS4 use x86 IC very similar to PC. The questions are:

1/ How can they keep those console systems protected from cracker and software privacy? What is the main method to protect copyright on those systems?

2/ Why not apply the same method to protect game/software on PC?

3/ Are those system Xbox and PS4 use another hardware protection not available on PC? If yes, what is it?

Comment: XBoxes and PlayStations are closed ecologies which lock their operating system to the hardware bootloader. Standard desktop PCs are sold to a different audience and do not include hardware locks. Attempts to introduce "secure computing" to IBM PCs have been rejected by customers as anticompetitive and paternalistic. Modern PC games for publishers that worry about piracy have opted to shift some or all of their game logic to the server-side, which is beyond the control of pirates.

Answer (score 1):

consoles these days are completely closed ecosystems, to the point where their components are not even interchangeable ( for example a Xbox internal hard drive cannot be inserted into another xbox, or the flash memory which stores the operating system and settings on the Nintendo 3ds is encrypted with a key which is unique to the console )

They are not user upgradable or servicible in the slightest , in addition to this there are many other protections built in ( for example on the Xbox 360 the majority of communication between major components on the motherboard are encrypted )

You are right in the sense that the majority of current console hardware is almost identical to consumer grade computers, but due to the fact that only signed code can be ran on the hardware ( and this is enforced via hardware and software )

Hell my 3ds is almost identical to my raspberry Pi at a low level, except for the fact that I can boot whatever the hell I want on my Pi

If a pc manufacturer was to enforce something like this they would loose the entire server market overnight .